# Entity auditing/versioning library for Java

Tags: library, java, version-control

I have to add auditing to my Spring Boot application.
I looked at Javers and Envers, but both seem to store the entire snapshot instead of just the changes made.
I am concerned that saving snapshots can consume a lot of disk space very quickly.
So, I am looking for a library which can store just the changes that happen.

I would also like to know if there are any down-sides of using the diff based auditing rather than snapshot based auditing.